Why does my flip card animation not work properly on the first click of the button after the page loads, but works correctly after that first click?
I am currently working on a flip card animation using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for my project. The animation works as expected when the "More" button is clicked and the card flips, revealing the back side. Similarly, clicking the "Back" button flips the card back to its original state.
However, I am facing an issue where the animation does not perform smoothly on the first click of the "More" button after the page loads. It flips but the animation effect is done partially, without 3d effect. Subsequent clicks work fine and trigger the animation in a proper way.
I have included my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code below for reference:
<div id="meal-card" class="card">
                        <div id="meal-card-front" class="card-front">
                            <div class="inline">
                                <h3 id="meal-name"></h3>
                                <p id="btn-container"><a id="btn-see-more" href="#<strong>More</strong></a></p>
                            </div>
                            <div><img id="meal-image" src=""></div>
                            <h4>Ingredients</h4>
                            <p id="ingredients"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="meal-card-back" class="card-back">
                            <div class="inline">
                                <h4>Instructions</h4>
                                <p id="btn-get-back"><a href="#"><strong>Back</strong></a></p>
                            </div>
                            <p id="instructions"></p>
                        </div>

.card {
    perspective: 1000px;
}


.card-front, .card-back{
    background: #fffcec;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 480px;
    height: 470px;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
}
  
.card-back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
  
/* This class is added to the card when it should flip */
.flipped .card-front{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
  
.flipped .card-back {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

var moreBtn = document.getElementById("btn-see-more");
var backBtn = document.getElementById("btn-get-back");

moreBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    mealCard.classList.add("flipped");
    $("#meal-card-back").show();
});

backBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    mealCard.classList.remove("flipped");
});

Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to ensure the flip card animation works smoothly even on the first click after page load?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

There seems to be an HTML syntax error near href="#<strong>More; see the the "Back" button's structure for reference. Also, the JavaScript variable mealCard appears undefined. If possible, please include a working example to help demonstrate the issue.

Not sure what is the mealCard in your original code since you've not included it in your JS code. I just tried to add this line and do some fixes on your HTML as some tags and quotations are missing. And it seems to work fine for me.
    var mealCard = document.getElementById('meal-card');



var moreBtn = document.getElementById('btn-see-more');
var backBtn = document.getElementById('btn-get-back');
var mealCard = document.getElementById('meal-card');

moreBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  mealCard.classList.add('flipped');
});

backBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  mealCard.classList.remove('flipped');
});
.card {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card-front,
.card-back {
  background: #fffcec;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 480px;
  height: 470px;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* This class is added to the card when it should flip */

.flipped .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipped .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <!--
      Need a visual blank slate?
      Remove all code in `styles.css`!
    -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="meal-card" class="card">
    <div id="meal-card-front" class="card-front">
      <div class="inline">
        <h3 id="meal-name"></h3>
        <p id="btn-container">
          <a id="btn-see-more" href="#">
            <strong>More</strong>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img id=" meal-image " src=" " />
      </div>
      <h4>Ingredients</h4>
      <p id="ingredients "></p>
    </div>
    <div id="meal-card-back" class="card-back">
      <div class="inline">
        <h4>Instructions</h4>
        <p id="btn-get-back">
          <a href="# ">
            <strong>Back</strong>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <p id="instructions "></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



Btw I guess this line is redundant since #meal-card-back is already shown?
    $("#meal-card-back").show();

